# Mix content over SSL

Tags: javascript, ssl, websocket, web

I was trying to setup a chatscript,  but I am getting Mix content error, bcoz I have SSL installed

```
Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws:<URL>/websocket'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.
```

The website and the chatscript is hosted on a sameserver with SSL enabled.

here is the URL 
https://afghanchat.net/client/htmlchat/1...hchat.html

Answer (score 1):

The WebSocket security model does not allow an insecure `ws:` URL to be accessed from a secure resource, such as a webpage served over HTTPS.  You must use a `wss:` URL instead.

The error message is complaining about an HTTPS webpage trying to access a `ws:` URL.

`http:` URLs are for HTTP resources accessed without SSL/TLS, and `https:` URLs are for HTTP resources accessed over SSL/TLS.  Likewise with WebSocket resources using `ws:` and `wss:` URLs, respectively.